# HTML5 or Qt5 & Qt Quick?

Tags: html, qt, embedded, qt5

I would like to ask, which one is mostly preferred development technology among HTML5 and qt5 ?; mainly on embedded devices by considering performance, animation effects. Also I would like to know few 'pros' and 'cons' of these two in embedded application development.

Comment: 'Embedded devices' covers everything from quite beefy ARM procs down to tiny microcontrollers, what device are you targeting?

Comment: Not decided one yet; but mostly I would prefer Beagle board ARM procs.